# Is there a way to replace a certain value in a list that is in another list with a value from a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace

I'm codding a kind of program to encrypt some text using matrices, and I need to replace some numbers in to letters. This is  my code so far:

```
letters = {"1": "A"}
X = [[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]]
for list_in in X:
    for number in list_in:
        new_value = letters[str(number)]
        list_in[number] = new_value
for row in X:
    print(row)
```

But, I'm getting the following error:

> KeyError: 'A'

I have no idea of what is wrong. Sorry if it is a bad question, but I didn't found any question similar to this one.

Comment: So you want to replace all the elements in the list (or list of lists) based on your `letters`, resulting something like`[['A', 'A', 'A'], ['A', 'A', 'A']]`?

Comment: @Chris Exactly!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Replacing item in a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104796/python-replacing-item-in-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your earlier code is the age-old one `Iterating on the list while modifying it`, which has caused the exception.

You are modifying `list_in` in the inner loop while iterating over it when you do `list_in[number] = new_value`, and this causes `new_value` to become `A` in the next loop, which is not a valid key in `letters`, hence you get the error `KeyError: 'A'`

I would suggest using list comprehension to achieve what you want, which creates a new list while iterating on the old one, which is what we would like to happen

```
letters = {"1": "A"}
X = [[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]]

res = [[letters[str(item)] for item in li] for li in X ]
print(res)
#[['A', 'A', 'A'], ['A', 'A', 'A']]
```

Note that the inner for loop can also be written in another way using `map`

```
letters = {"1": "A"}
X = [[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]]

res = [list(map(lambda x:letters[str(x)], li)) for li in X ]
print(res)
```

Note that this is equivalent to the following traditional double for loops, which might be easier to understand

```
letters = {"1": "A"}
X = [[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]]

res = []
#Iterate over outer list
for li in X:
    l = []
    #Iterate over inner list and append A for inner list
    for item in li:
        l.append(letters[str(item)])
    #Append this list to a bigger list
    res.append(l)

print(res)
```

As an addendum, the original code can be made to work by using indexes to change the value instead of replacing items, using `enumerate`

```
letters = {"1": "A"}
X = [[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]]

#Iterate over the lists
for i, li in enumerate(X):
    for j, item in enumerate(li):
        #Replace value at index i,j with A
        X[i][j] = letters[str(item)]

print(X)
```

Comment: One of the versions is mine

Comment: Your code actually will not work and throw an exception which I fixed @U9-Forward ! Hence it's slightly different than yours, in any case, I can remove that part if you want :)

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Edited

Comment: Great! Glad you find the issue, so if you want, I can remove the part from my answer now @U9-Forward !

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Nah, keep it like this, +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension with `list(map(...))`:

```
print([list(map(lambda x: letters[str(x)], i)) for i in X])
```

That which outputs:

```
[['A', 'A', 'A'], ['A', 'A', 'A']]
```

Comment: @Vitor happy to help :-)